# PHP File Uploading working in local but not working in server

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, xampp

As I'm uploading a `csv` file in localhost it is correctly working. All the validations are done but while uploading the file online it is not working. The file is refreshing itself.This is my sample code

```
$data['error'] = '';    //initialize image upload error array to empty                                                                                                     
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'csv';
$config['max_size'] = '10000';

$this->load->library('upload', $config);

if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) 
{
   $data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
   $data['mainpage']='category';
   $data['mode']='addcsv';
   $this->load->view('includes/mainpage',$data);
}                                                                           
else 
{
   $file_data = $this->upload->data();                                                                                                               
   $file_path =  './uploads/'.$file_data['file_name'];
```

Comment: I bet you don't have the same apache configuration in local and on the server.

Comment: you can display the error, you can get more message from it.

Comment: PLease put some code it would be easier to help you

Comment: can you show us your code and also saved data in database

Answer (score 0):

Please check your write permission to the directory you want to upload.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any error messages thrown while uploading the file?

Also make sure that you have set the correct permissions to the upload directory you are trying to upload the file to.

It would also be nice with some code.

Comment: no iam not getting any error message just getting the page refresh but in local it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use move_uploaded_file() function like below

```
move_uploaded_file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'.$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

Comment: I didnt get this were to use

Answer (score 0):

What's the output of $this->upload->display_errors(); ?

You can also check the folder permissions on the server (0777)